# How to display images in the same size - with filled space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have specified a maximum width for my pictures. Now I have the problem that the pictures are not the same in height. Is there a way to fill in the missing height with a white area (same size at the top and bottom) so that the maximum height is reached but the image is not distorted?

My code:

```html
<div class="w3-row-padding">
  <div class="filterDiv master">
    <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">Master</div>
        <img src="Img/5.jpg" alt="House" style="width:99%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filterDiv master">
    <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">Master</div>
        <img src="Img/6.jpg" alt="House" style="width:99%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filterDiv master">
    <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">Master</div>
        <img src="Img/7.jpg" alt="House" style="width:99%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filterDiv master">
    <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">Master</div>
        <img src="Img/8.jpg" alt="House" style="width:99%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

w3school framework used.

Comment: How is this a javascript/php question?

Comment: I code just in my freetime, i dont know if there are some ways to do that in js/php.

Comment: set a background with `background-color` in the parent element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
img {
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

hope this works

Comment: looks better but the pictures are zoomed in. I would like to keep the original size and just filled the "empty spaces"

Comment: Just add/update: object-fit: contain; and background-color: white; and it works

Answer (score 0):

a good practice is to give for each  parent `div` which are the `w3-col` divs a `background-image` and a common `class` which specifies other needed `background` properties and the wanted height which is `200px`. thereby, the images will not be stretched since the divs are the ones that are specified with the wanted `height`.

The `HTML` Code will be:

```html
 <div class="w3-row-padding">
        <div class="filterDiv master">
            <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
                <div class="w3-display-container img-container1 img-container ">
                    <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding ">Master
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filterDiv master">
            <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom img-container2 img-container ">
                <div class="w3-display-container">
                    <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding ">Master</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filterDiv master">
            <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
                <div class="w3-display-container  img-container3 img-container ">
                    <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">Master</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filterDiv master">
            <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
                <div class="w3-display-container img-container4 img-container ">
                    <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding ">Master</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

given the following `CSS`

```css
.img-container {
    height: 200px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.img-container1 {
    background-image: url("Img/5.jpg");

}

.img-container2 {
    background-image: url("Img/6.jpg");

}

.img-container3 {
    background-image: url("Img/7.jpg");


}

.img-container4 {
    background-image: url("Img/8.jpg");


}
```